# How to import a module, which imports another module, from two different folders inside a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

Assuming I have a python package with the following structure:

```
folder1
   __init__.py
   main.py
   subfolder1
      __init__.py
      submain.py
      subagent.py (contains class Agent)
      subnetwork.py (contains class Network)
```

In the `subagent.py` file I import the Network class and in `main.py` and `submain.py` I import the Agent class. I would like to be able to start my program from both `main.py` and `submain.py`. However this causes problem in the `subagent.py` file. If I start from `main.py` I have to write the imports in `subagent.py` like that:

```
from subfolder1.subnetwork import Network
```

However if I start from `submain.py` I have to write the imports in `subagent.py` like that:

```
from subnetwork import Network
```

Is there an elegant solution to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute imports, i.e. starting with `folder1`: `from folder1 import ...` or `import folder1`. Call your *mains* like so: `python -m folder1.main` and `python -m folder1.subfolder1.submain`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try except blocks to import both ways

```py
try:
    from subnetwork import Network
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from subfolder1.subnetwork import Network
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the working directory?

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":  # Only change the working directory if the file is run directly
    os.chdir('..') # Move up a level so that it is the same as main
# now run the imports
```